# CPTCalendarFormatter stringForObjectValue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, core-plot, xcode8

When I start using Xcode8 and try to build the project and I got this error

> Nullability specifier 'nonnull' conflicts with existing specifier 'nullable'

on `Coreplot` library that I install using `Cocoapod`

the error occurred on this method

```
-(nullable NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(nonnull id)coordinateValue
{
  NSInteger componentIncrement = 0;

  if ( [coordinateValue respondsToSelector:@selector(integerValue)] ) {
      componentIncrement = [coordinateValue integerValue];
  }
...
```

Comment: What does the .h file have for that method? The error seems to indicate that the `coordinateValue` parameter is `nullable` and you are mistakenly declaring it as `nonnull`.

Comment: No, this one is define in CorePlot library itself.
The CPTCalendarFormatter is the extension of NSNumberFormatter

@interface CPTCalendarFormatter : NSNumberFormatter

Comment: See https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/302

Comment: Great, thanks. Let's wait for the next release of `coreplot`